# oracle date format (auto convert)

Tags: oracle, date

I have problem with understanding one issue.
Assume that a parameter `nls_date_format` is set to `dd-mon-rr`, 
then if there is a table with column which contains date type I can insert data there only if statement looks like this:

```
insert into table values ('01-jan-00')
```

or '01-january-00' instead of jan. Date 01-01-00 cannot be inserted (invalid month).

On the other site, when the nls_date_format parameter is set to `dd-mm-rr` I can insert date in format either '01-jan-00' or '01-01-01' or even '01-january-00' . There is no invalid month error. So how does it work, oracle can convert date from string (january) to number(01), but cannot convert date from number (01) to string(january)?

Comment: Is the string `01` supposed to be converted to the month January the year  2001 or the first day of the month? `January` can't be a day of the month or a year.

Comment: I actually think this is a moot question; you should *never* rely on implicit conversions when working with the DATE or TIMESTAMP datatypes; it's not that difficult to use `to_date()`/`to_timestamp()` or the `DATE` / `TIMESTAMP` literals to explicitly convert your dates and timestamps!

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Actually, I dont have any interest in converting it. The question is why an error is produced when inserting date '05-01-00' when nls_date_format is dd-mon-yy (expecting string as a month but given number, so produces an error, ok) but there is no error when inserting date '05-jan-00' when nls_date_format is dd-mm-yy (expecting number as a month but given string.. and no error?)

Comment: @Boneist thanks, I know about this function, I am asking because of certification exam, there are weird questions in there ;p

Comment: @luk_asz94, you asked why. The why is most likely because without explicit information on how to interpret `01` it is ambiguous and the programmers who created Oracle decided to raise an error instead of pulling an interpretation from their nether regions. The also decided to be helpful and convert `January` into the month of `January` because it was "safe" to do so. This is all speculative since I have never spoken to anyone who is a programmer at Oracle.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Yep, probably you are right. I was hoping to find a logical explanation, but it seems that programmer did it the way they did and I have to remember this rather than thinking whether it is logical. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

> **String-to-Date Conversion Rules**
> .....
> .....
>
> - If a match fails between a datetime format element and the corresponding characters in the date string, then Oracle attempts alternative format elements, as shown in Table 2-18.

```
**Table 2-18 Oracle Format Matching**
Original Format Element | Additional Format Elements to Try in Place of the Original
------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------
'MM'                    | 'MON' and 'MONTH'
'MON'                   | 'MONTH'
'MONTH'                 | 'MON'
'YY'                    | 'YYYY'
'RR'                    | 'RRRR'
```

---

According to the above, all conversions listed below work without any error:

```
alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE='American';

select to_date('21-jan-2014',     'dd-month-yyyy' ) from dual;
select to_date('21-january-2014', 'dd-mon-yyyy' )   from dual;

select to_date('21-january-2014', 'dd-mm-rrrr' ) from dual;
select to_date('21-jan-2014',     'dd-mm-rrrr' ) from dual;

select to_date('21-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yy' )   from dual;
select to_date('21-01-14',   'dd-mm-yyyy' ) from dual;

select to_date('21-01-2014', 'dd-mm-rr' )   from dual;
select to_date('21-01-14',   'dd-mm-rrrr' ) from dual;


alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE='Polish';

select to_date('21-sty-2014',     'dd-month-yyyy' ) from dual;
select to_date('21-styczeń-2014', 'dd-mon-yyyy' ) from dual;

select to_date('21-styczeń-2014', 'dd-mm-rrrr' ) from dual;
select to_date('21-sty-2014',     'dd-mm-rrrr' ) from dual;
```